# How does a SQLAlchemy Session manage transactions, when executing multiple raw SQL statements at once?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

None of the "similar questions" really get at this specific topic, but I am trying to find out how SQLAlchemy's `Session` handles transactions, when:

1. Passing raw SQL text to the `execute()` method, rather than utilizing any SQLAlchemy model objects, AND
2. The raw SQL text contains multiple distinct commands.

For instance:

```py
bulk_operation = """
   DELETE FROM the_table WHERE id = ...;

   INSERT INTO the_table (id, name) VALUES (...);
"""

sql = text(bulk_operation)
session.execute(sql.bindparams(id=foo, name=bar))
```

The goal here is to restore the original state, if either the `DELETE` or the `INSERT` fails for any reason.

But does `Session.execute()` actually guarantee this, in this context?  Is it necessary to include `BEGIN` and `COMMIT` commands within the raw SQL text itself, or manage from the Python level with `session.commit()` or something else?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: I suspect it depends on whether the underlying DB-API connector permits multiple statements in calls to `cursor.execute`.